# Exclude Cartopy elements from Matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm plotting scatter points onto a map and seeing unwanted rectangles in my legend, despite the insertion of `label='_nolegend_'`:

```
# import functions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt

# Create a Stamen terrain background instance
stamen_terrain = cimgt.Stamen('terrain-background')
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=stamen_terrain.crs, label='_nolegend_')

# Set range of map, stipulate zoom level
ax.set_extent([-122.7, -121.5, 37.15, 38.15], crs=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.add_image(stamen_terrain, 12, label='_nolegend_')

# Add scatter point
ax.scatter(-122.4194, 37.7749, s=55, c='k', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())    
ax.legend(('','','San Francisco'), loc = 3)
plt.show()
```

How to remove the rectangles, and just show the scatter point in the legend?

[image: Legend has unwanted rectangles]

Comment: Could you help people reproduce this? (I get `AttributeError: module 'cartopy.io.img_tiles' has no attribute 'Stamen'` when running your code.)

Comment: With `Cartopy 0.17.0` I can't reproduce your `AttributeError`. According to [this](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/cartopy/io/img_tiles.html), `cartopy.io.img_tiles` does indeed have attribute `Stamen`.

Comment: I see. In cartopy 0.16 (which is the latest version conda will install for me) it would be  `cimgt.StamenTerrain()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set labels for each of the elements in the axes via `('','','San Francisco')`. Instead just set the label to the scatter itself

```
ax.scatter(..., label="Some City")
ax.legend(loc=3)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to give the scatter a label, you can pass the handle and label to the `legend`:

```
sc = ax.scatter(...)    
ax.legend(handles=[sc], labels=['Some City'], loc = 3)
```